# MVC How to pass a list of objects with List Items POST action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to post a List of items to controller from Razor view , but i am getting a List of objects as null
My class structre is

Model:

```
List<Subjects> modelItem

class Subjects
{
    int SubId{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    List<Students> StudentEntires{get;set;}
}

class StudentEntires
{
    int StudId{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    int Mark{get;set;}
}
```

The model itself is a list of items and every items contain List of child items as well. Example model is a list of Subjects and every subject contains a List of Students, and i want to input mark for every student

My View is like

```
@model IList<Subjects>  
@{   
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   if (Model.Count > 0)
   {
       @for (int item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
       {
           <b>@Model[item].Name</b><br />
           @foreach (StudentEntires markItem in Model[item].StudentEntires)
           {
               @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => markItem.Mark)
           }
       }
       <p style="text-align:center">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
       </p>
    }
}
```

And in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OptionalMarks(int Id,ICollection<Subjects> model)
    {
        //BUt my model is null. Any idea about this?
    }
```

Comment: how are you sending the model to the view in the `OptionalMarks` GET method?

Comment: Yes exactly. First find a list of subjects and for each subjects , get a list of students

Answer (score 27):

You're finding this difficult because you're not utilising the full power of the MVC framework, so allow me to provide a working example.

First up, let's create a view model to encapsulate your view's data requirements:

```
public class SubjectGradesViewModel
{
    public SubjectGradesViewModel()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }

    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create a class to represent your subject model:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> StudentEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, a class to represent a student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

At this point, you have all the classes you need to represent your data.  Now let's create two controller actions, including some sample data so you can see how this works:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SubjectGradesViewModel();

    // This sample data would normally be fetched
    // from your database
    var compsci = new Subject
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Computer Science",
        StudentEntries = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student { Id = 1, Name = "CompSci 1" },
            new Student { Id = 2, Name = "CompSci 2" },
        }
    };

    var maths = new Subject
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Mathematics",
        StudentEntries = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Maths 1" },
            new Student { Id = 4, Name = "Maths 2" },
        }
    };

    model.Subjects.Add(compsci);
    model.Subjects.Add(maths);

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SubjectGradesViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }

    // There were validation errors
    // so redisplay the form
    return View(model);
}
```

Now it's time to construct the views, and this part is particularly important when it comes to sending data back to a controller.  First up is the `Index` view:

```
@model SubjectGradesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subjects) <br />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

You'll notice I'm simply using `Html.EditorFor`, whilst passing `Subjects` as the parameter.  The reason I'm doing this is because we're going to create an `EditorTemplate` to represent a `Subject`.  I'll explain more later on.  For now, just know that `EditorTemplates` and `DisplayTemplates` are special folder names in MVC, so their names, and locations, are important.

We're actually going to create two templates: one for `Subject` and one for `Student`.  To do that, follow these steps:

1. Create an `EditorTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\EditorTemplates`).
2. Create a strongly-typed view in that directory with the name that matches your model (i.e. in this case you would make two views, which would be called `Subject.cshtml` and `Student.cshtml`, respectively (again, the naming is important)).

`Subject.cshtml` should look like this:

```
@model Subject

<b>@Model.Name</b><br />

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StudentEntries)
```

`Student.cshtml` should look like this:

```
@model Student

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name): @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Grade)
<br />
```

That's it.  If you now build and run this application, putting a breakpoint on the `POST` index action, you'll see the model is correctly populated.

So, what are `EditorTemplates`, and their counterparts, `DisplayTemplates`?  They allow you to create reusable portions of views, allowing you to organise your views a little more.

The great thing about them is the templated helpers, that is `Html.EditorFor` and `Html.DisplayFor`, are smart enough to know when they're dealing with a template for a collection.  That means you no longer have to loop over the items, manually invoking a template each time.  You also don't have to perform any `null` or `Count()` checking, because the helpers will handle that all for you.  You're left with views which are clean and free of logic.

`EditorTemplates` also generate appropriate names when you want to POST collections to a controller action.  That makes model binding to a list much, much simpler than generating those names yourself.  There are times where you'd still have to do that, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Answer (score 2):

Change the action method signature to

`public ActionResult OptionalMarks(ICollection<Subjects> model)`

Since in your HTML, it does not look like there is anything named `Id` in there. This isn't your main issue though.

Next, do the following with the foor loop

```
@for(int idx = 0; idx < Model[item].StudentEntires.Count();idx++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => Model[item].StudentEntries[idx])
}
```

Possibly due to the use of a `foreach` loop for the `StudentEntries`, the model binder is having trouble piecing everything together, and thus a NULL is returned.

EDIT:

Here's an example:

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

        var subjects = new List<Subject>();
        var subject1 = new Subject();

        subject1.Name = "History";
        subject1.StudentEntires.Add(new Student { Mark = 50 });
        subjects.Add(subject1);

        viewModel.Subjects = subjects;

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model SOWorkbench.Controllers.IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (Model.Subjects.Any())
    {
        int subjectsCount = Model.Subjects.Count();
        for (int item = 0; item < subjectsCount; item++)
        {
            <b>@Model.Subjects[item].Name</b><br />            
            int studentEntriesCount = Model.Subjects[item].StudentEntires.Count();

            for(int idx = 0;idx < studentEntriesCount;idx++)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(_ => Model.Subjects[item].StudentEntires[idx].Mark);
            }
        }
        <p style="text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
        </p>
    }
}
```

When you post the form, you should see the data come back in the `viewModel` object.

Comment: I conveerted code like this, but  still getting child list as null ( But only StudentEntries List ). The main model list is not empty ie    SubId , Name is not null but  StudentEntires list is null