# Post Action Send simple list MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just reading this thread: [MVC How to pass a list of objects with List Items POST action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064291/mvc-how-to-pass-a-list-of-objects-with-list-items-post-action-method)

**Controller - Get Method**

```
public ActionResult CheckStep1(int id)
{
  var vm = new List<CheckStep>();
  return View(vm);
}
```

**But always my controller receive the parameter as null**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckStep1(ICollection<CheckStep> model)
{
  //TODO - here models is null
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**The View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("CheckStep1", "MyController", FormMethod.Post)))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CheckStep.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckStep[i].Id)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckStep[i].name)
      </td>
    </tr>
  }  
})
```

I checked in my `fiddler` and all the parameters are in the URL, but for some reason the controller always get a null value

**fiddler log**

```
POST http://localhost:5773/MyController/CheckStep1/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5773
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:5773/MyController/CheckStep1/1
Content-Length: 5205
model.Id=1&model.name=Jonh&model.Id=2&model.name=Kath
```

Comment: We have no idea what the form post looks like, so how are we supposed to answer this question? *I checked in my fiddler and all the parameters are in the URL* - post action arguments are bound from the *form body*, not the URL.

Comment: Show your view. The question you link to isn't that clear, see for example [Posting to a list<modeltype> MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3) for some more examples.

Comment: I updated the fiddler los @AntP

Comment: @CodeCaster I edited my post, I included the view

Comment: Yeah see duplicate. Replace your `foreach` loop with the code shown there in the accepted answer's `for` loop.

Comment: @CodeCaster I replaced the `foreach` for a `for` loop, but the contoller always get a `null` for this property

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual code and the steps you perform to get data to post? Because you provide an empty list, how should it post data back?

Comment: @CodeCaster code updated

Comment: There still isn't enough information in your post to troubleshoot the issue. Your Fiddler log is not what is posted with your updated code, and you didn't show how you make it post new list items when the list initially is null.

Comment: You edited view code makes no sense and will throw an exception. Is the model `List<CheckStep>`? Why are you looping the `FactibilidadesConstruccion` property and rendering the `Id` and `name` properties of it's parent `CheckStep`? You need to show the real view code including the `@model` definition