# Posting model back to controller containing complex collection

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I've posted a question similar to this, but I don't believe it clearly stated my question correctly. So here goes a better explanation!

I'm working on a C# MVC 5 application. I have a page that dynamically lists the model's collection property **A**. Each item in this collection uses a bit of bootstrap to show/hide it's own collection property **B**. So just to clarify that: This model has a collection of objects each of which has a collection of objects associated with it. These objects each have a checkbox associated with them bound to an isChecked boolean too that can be used to select/deselect items. Checking a box of an item from collection **A**, automatically selects all checkboxes of its collection **B**. So, as you can perhaps see, the sole purpose of having a checkbox on collection **A** items, is to act as a select all for its associated collection **B** items.

I'm trying to pass the entire model back to the controller on POST and then do stuff with it, e.g. grab all items that have their , but am running into a few problems.

E.g.

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
  var headerId = category.Name;
  var childCounter = 0;
  @*some divs and headers here*@

  @if (category.Items.Any())
  {
    @*lets give it the ability to check all of its associated items*@
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => category.IsChecked, new {id = @headerId, onclick = String.Format("CheckUncheckChildren({0}, {1})", @headerId, category.MenuItems.Count)})
  }
  else
  {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => category.IsChecked)
  }

  @*some other divs and headings*@
  @if (category.MenuItems.Any())
  {
     @foreach (var item in dealItemCategory.MenuItems)
     {
       var childId = childCounter++ + "_" + headerId;
       var serverId = item.Id;

       @*some other divs and headings*@
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => item.IsChecked, new {id = @childId})
     }
  }
}
```

Lower down on the page I have:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count(); i++)
  {    
    var category = Model.Categories.ElementAt(i);
    var headerId = category.Name;
    @Html.HiddenFor(d => category, new {id = @headerId})

    for (var j = 0; j < Model.Categories.ElementAt(i).Items.Count(); j++)
    {
      var item = Model.Categories.ElementAt(i).Items.ElementAt(j);     
      @Html.HiddenFor(d => item, new {id = j + "_" + @headerId})
    }
  }
```

In my mind, I'm retaining these properties on the page for this complex collection... (not that my understanding is 100%) I've forced ids for these hidden fields so that they correlate with the ids of the Checkboxes. Maybe not the best idea, but it was just the last thing I tried to get this to work...

Now I have two options here:

**1)** Believe in the above to mean that whenever a checkbox is selected/deselected, the object in the collection it is associated with, will get its isChecked boolean changed. Then, POST back the entire model and hope I'll be able to cycle through all checked items and do awesome stuff.

**or**

**2)** Create a string property in the model to hold a JSON representation of this complex collection of objects. When the page is POSTED, update this JSON string to the state of the complex collection that has been hopefully updated to have some of its items checked/unchecked. Then, POST back the entire model and server-side I would deserialize this single object into a logically equivalent complex collection and work from there.
I.e.
My model change would be adding a property:

```
public string JsonCategories{ get; set; }
```

And then in the view I'd have to initiate a post back:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.JsonCategories);

function accept() {
  var categories= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Categories));
  var jsonCategories = JSON.stringify(categories);
  var a = $('#JsonCategories').val();
  $('#JsonCategories').val(jsonCategories );
  $("form").submit();
};
```

**Attempting solution A**, I either get a null for the Categories property, or if I add @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.Categories); I get an empty object, count of 0.

**Attempting solution B**, I do get a lovely JSON representation for the complex Categories back in server land, but I see checkboxes I checked aren't changing the isChecked bools leading me to believe that, while the JSON object is able to be set to the Categories object on POST client-side, everything done by the user isn't being kept so ultimately the Categories collection of the model hasn't changed since it was passed to the View initially.

Sorry if this all seems complicated, it is and for a junior like me, I thought it best I ask around as I've never posted back lists and stuff to the controller before.

I'd be happy to provide more information if it will help!

Warmest regards,

Comment: You cannot use `foreach` loops or `ElementAt(i)` to generate form controls that will bind to collections. Your generating `name` attributes without indexers that have no relationship to your model. You collections need to implement `IList<T>` and you need to use nested `for` loops (or alternatively use custom EditorTemplates for your types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your foreach loops to for loops you can make use of the loop index in the lambda expression. This should make the engine output the correct syntax for posting the values. For example:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count(); i++)
{
    ...
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.Categories[i].IsChecked)
    ...
}
```

This should correctly bind the values to the POST request. The resulting html will be similar to the following snippet (0 being the first item, 1 would be the second etc.):

```
<input name="Categories[0].IsChecked" ... ></input>
```

Alternatively you can create editor templates for your child collections, which will result in you writing out this snippet to replace where your for loop is currently.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Categories)
```

More on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21065918/4244733).

This should help you go with option 1.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I've gone the editor template route and am happy to announce that my model now has everything I need! You sir, are a hero!